# Identity role conflict for a user by comparing two columns

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm currently working on a requirement to identify role conflicts for a user based on a configured conflict mapping matrix. The formula should look for the user role(s) and compare it with the conflict mapping and display the findings.

[image: sample screenshot]

Can someone help me in writing a vlookup formula. Here is the link to the google docs on the sample data that I'm currently working.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gPhJyH-sPprdPO3jBtBv2SN1hKVkHf3KBiv3BLJn7l0/edit#gid=0

Since I had a basic knowledge on vlookups, i'm not sure how to use nested vlookups.

Thanks in Advance!
Vj

Comment: Thank you for your comment. From the spreadsheet, if Mike has RRR Asset Inquiry
and Asset Accountant roles, then it should specify Conflict, becoz as per the role conflict 1 and 2 matrix, that combination is a conflict

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is not a nested VLookup, but a way to find out all combinations of roles for a given user.

e.g. for user Mike,
You can put all his roles vertically in cell C18:C22, then put all his roles horizontally in cell D17:H17

[image: role combinations]

Then in cell D18, write below formula to get all combinations:

```
=C18:C22&"|"&D17:H17
```

Then you just need to check whether any of those combinations match your conflict matrix.

e.g in D24, you can use below formula:

```
=OR(D18=$E$2:$E$9&"|"&$F$2:$F$9)
```

You can drag that formula from D24 to H28.